# How to fix string structures in IDA

Tags: ida

As part of exercise in RE I noticed that some string is not appear correctly in the code.

I have the following code:
[image]

In the orange colour the string doesn't appear correctly.
In the red it appear correctly.

I want that the code in the orange will be like the one in the red.

We can see that in address `0x10751` we have:

```
push offset word_107DE ; SourceString
```

At the address of `word_107DE (0x107DE)` the string appears as:

```
word_107DE dw '\'
aDosedevicesPr_0:
    unicode 0, <DosDevices\ProceHelper>, 0
```

In `0x107DE` we have an extra row:

```
word_107DE dw '\'
```

How can I fix it and merge this row to be like this:

```
aDosedevicesPr_0:
    unicode 0, <\DosDevices\ProceHelper>, 0
```

And after this I hope to see the name of the string in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the cursor to `word_107DE`, press <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (or Options/Ascii String style from the menu), and click the Unicode button.

Comment: Btw, how can I make IDA to print it as a comment? I thought it will be automatically once I did your solution.